#  gdbm programming with C

Tags: c, gdbm

I am trying to learn gnu gdbm programming with C but can't proceed due to the paucity of the gdbm tutorial, books etc. so the only thing I have to follow is couple of simple gdbm c api codes available on w3. I wrote and compiled the following code by the help of two separate .c files but **it can't fetch data** from the database "testdb" so please tell me where it goes wrong. First it 
stores a string and, in the second part, it fetches the data. Output is; 
key not found.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gdbm.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
  GDBM_FILE dbf;
  datum key = { "testkey", 7 };     /* key, length */
  datum value = { "testvalue", 9 }; /* value, length */

  printf ("Storing key-value pair... \n");

  dbf = gdbm_open("testdb", 0, GDBM_NEWDB,0666, 0);
  gdbm_store (dbf, key, value, GDBM_INSERT);
  printf ("key: %s size: %d\n", key.dptr, key.dsize);
  gdbm_close (dbf);
  printf ("done.\n\n");

   dbf = gdbm_open("testdb", 0, GDBM_READER, 0666, 0);
   if (!dbf)
   {
      fprintf (stderr, "File %s either doesn't exist or is not a gdbm file.\n", "testdb");
      exit (1);
   }

   key.dsize = strlen("testkey") + 1;

   value = gdbm_fetch(dbf, key);

   if (value.dsize > 0) {
      printf ("%s\n", value.dptr);
      free (value.dptr);
   } 
    else {
      printf ("Key %s not found.\n", key.dptr);
   }
   gdbm_close (dbf);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Include trailing '\0' in length.

```
  datum key = { "testkey", 8 };     /* key, length */
  datum value = { "testvalue", 10 }; /* value, length */
```

---

-- Edit:

Regarding the link you comment with: http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/gdbm/example.html

Read first bullet point carefully: *"I'm assuming that the process which wrote the key and data included the terminating null character. …"*

So; **either**:

```
datum key = { "testkey", 8 }; /* Include \0 in length */
datum value = { "testvalue", 10 };
```

And:

```
key.dsize = strlen("testkey") + 1; /* +1 for the trailing \0 */
```

**or**

```
datum key = { "testkey", 7 }; /* Skip \0 in length */
datum value = { "testvalue", 9 };
```

And:

```
key.dsize = strlen("testkey"); /* Do not +1 */
```

First *version* is often preferred as c-strings that's not null terminated can be a pain to work with.

Hope it helps.

---

-- Edit 2 (sorry, keep thinking of new things):

Also note that if you say i.e.:

```
datum value = { "testvalue", 5 }; /* value, length */
```

The value stored would be "testv".

Comment: **Thank you very much for your kind help.** Now it's ok and gives the desired output. I took the content from the following two .c files: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_22.html used to store data and the fetch part I wrote based on this file - http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/gdbm/example.html I wonder why they didn't add the NULL char at the end of two strings in their code (network-theory.co.uk) where it seems impossible to store data without '\0'.

Comment: **Thanks again.** I got the point. I really failed to notice it due to exhaustion as I had been trying to solve the problem for the last 24 hrs.(sometimes with gdb - gdb showed key size was <0 and I couldn't detect the reason). But without your help and favour, I wouldn't be able to solve it because I haven't got any experience either in gdbm or in c. Thanks.

Comment: @Bishnu: Your're welcome. You might find this page useful: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info. I'd recommend you read "The C Programming Language (Second edition)". (Keep in mind it is written for c89 standard; but it is still _the_ book.) Also "Expert C Programming: Deep C Secrets" has, among other things, some interesting facts about the language and its history: gives you a understanding of "why is it like this or that" – which can be very useful when learning.

Comment: Yes. I have bought the book "C Programming Language, 2nd edition" with "C answer book" by Tondo (answer book book is very good) and I have just got a copy of "Deep C Secretes" so surely it can be of great help. Thank you. :)